# Unable to run an executable built with NASM

Tags: compiling, executable, linker, assembly

I am attempting to assemble the assembly source file below using the following NASM command:

```
nasm -f elf -o test.o test.asm
```

This completes without errors and I then try to link an executable with `ld`:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -e main -o test test.o -lc
```

This also appears to succeed and I then try to run the executable:

```
$ ./test
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I tried running `ldd` on the executable:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf777f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7598000)
/usr/lib/libc.so.1 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7780000)
```

I installed the `lsb-core` package and verified that `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` exists. How come I still can't run the executable?

I'm attempting to do this on a machine running the 64-bit edition of Ubuntu 15.04.

The source code:

```
; This code has been generated by the 7Basic
; compiler <http://launchpad.net/7basic>

extern printf
extern scanf
extern read
extern strlen
extern strcat
extern strcpy
extern strcmp
extern malloc
extern free

; Initialized data

      SECTION .data
s_0 db "Hello, World!",0
printf_i: db "%d",10,0
printf_s: db "%s",10,0
printf_f: db "%f",10,0
scanf_i: db "%d",0
scanf_f: db "%lf",0
; Uninitialized data

      SECTION .bss
v_12 resb 4
v_0  resb 4
v_4  resb 8

      SECTION .text

; Code

global main
  main:
finit
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push 0
pop eax
mov [v_12], eax
    l_0:
mov eax, [v_12]
push eax
push 5
pop edx
pop eax
cmp eax, edx
jl l_2
push 0
jmp l_3
    l_2:
push 1
    l_3:
pop eax
cmp eax, 0
je l_1
push s_0
push printf_s
call printf
add esp, 8
mov eax, [v_12]
push eax
push 1
pop edx
pop eax
add eax, edx
push eax
pop eax
mov [v_12], eax
jmp l_0
    l_1:
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
mov eax,0
ret
```

Here's the output of `strings test`:

```
/usr/lib/libc.so.1
libc.so.6
strcpy
printf
strlen
read
malloc
strcat
scanf
strcmp
free
GLIBC_2.0
t'hx
Hello, World!
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.interp
.hash
.dynsym
.dynstr
.gnu.version
.gnu.version_r
.rel.plt
.text
.eh_frame
.dynamic
.got.plt
.data
.bss
test.7b.out
printf_i
printf_s
printf_f
scanf_i
scanf_f
v_12
_DYNAMIC
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
strcmp@@GLIBC_2.0
read@@GLIBC_2.0
printf@@GLIBC_2.0
free@@GLIBC_2.0
_edata
strcat@@GLIBC_2.0
strcpy@@GLIBC_2.0
malloc@@GLIBC_2.0
scanf@@GLIBC_2.0
strlen@@GLIBC_2.0
_end
__bss_start
main
```

Comment: Just so I understand, you're assembling x86 (i386) 32-bit code on a 64-bit installation?

Comment: Can you try: ld -m elf_i386 -e main -o test test.o -lc -I /path/ld-linux.so.2 ?

Comment: @taliezin: Just tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Gilles Here we go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11552354/

Comment: That `/usr/lib/libc.so.1` should probably be `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`. No idea how it got there.

Comment: I was actually just able to (sort of) get it working by changing the `ld` command to `ld -m elf_i386 -e main -o test test.o -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2`. It runs, but encounters a segfault. I'm not sure if that is related to this issue however or just a bug with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also link start up fragments like `crt1.o` and others if you want to call libc functions.  The linking process can be very complicated, so you'd better use `gcc` for that.

On amd64 Ubuntu, you can:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
gcc -m32 -o test test.o
```

You can see files and commands for the link by adding `-v` option.